# AndEngine: Load textures dynamically during game

Tags: android, andengine

In my game I need to load textures during game (in character customization screen, for loading the different skins). But when I do it, UI is blocked. This is the code:

```
private static void loadSkinTextureRegions(){
    sTexture.clearTextureAtlasSources();
    sTextureRegionA = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(sTexture, context, getFileNameA(), 0, 0); 
    sTextureRegionB = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(sTexture, context, getFileNameB(), 0, 406); 
}
```

So I thought: "I can run this code using an AsyncTask". So I tried, and now UI is not blocked but... sometimes textures are not loaded, and don't know why!?

There is any way to load textures dinamically without blocking the thread?

Edit: Doing texture change using AsyncTask, sometimes I get this error:

```
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1622
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:152)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:137)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.reloadToHardware(Texture.java:162)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:239)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:613)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1525)
09-20 09:43:59.218: E/AndroidRuntime(21976):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1242)
```

If I do it synchronous, works well, but it blocks thread and it's annoying

Comment: How are you sure the textures aren't being loaded?  Have you noticed a pattern when the loading appears to have failed?

Comment: Textures are not loaded because the sprite disappears. I have not noticed any pattern. I put a button for change the texture, and I touch it several times, so texture changes each time I touch it, and sometimes the sprite disappears, and if I touch the button again, the sprite turns visible again :(

Comment: Can you post the whole Logcat?  That doesn't point toward any of of your code.

Comment: The code is the code I posted. I see that fails because I remove and add texture sources from another thread while andengine is iterating over it

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the Texture after every  creation of  texture Regions.
in your case

```
       private static void loadSkinTextureRegions(){
        sTexture.clearTextureAtlasSources();
        sTextureRegionA = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(sTexture, context, getFileNameA(), 0, 0); 
        sTextureRegionB = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(sTexture, context, getFileNameB(), 0, 406); 
 sTexture.load();

    }
```

and also youcan place loadSkinTextureRegions() in UIThread.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same. Sometimes the sprite disappears (when I made a texture change) :(